# Changing the directory from which ClassLoader looks in for Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, classloader

The web application I am working on uses a certain resource. For testing purposes, I want it to use a different resource with the same name but in different directory. I use classloader to load the resources. Currently it always loads the resource from the test/resources directory. I want to be able to tell it to be able to get it from a different directory (when not testing) without changing the code.

This is how I used ClassLoader:

```
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream file =loader.getResourceAsStream("resource.xml");
```

So, when I deploy the web-app (jetty container), I need to also modify something or somehow give it a different classpath or place to look since I have resources that are different for testing and the main use.

Comment: If you're using maven-jetty-plugin, the files from within the test/resources directory shouldn't be loaded when running the web application. Maven excludes test/java and test/resources when building a project, so you should be able to use "resource.xml" during testing and deployment while having it reference different physical resources.

Comment: alright so where should my other resource.xml file be place? (the one for deployment)